# C# Dynamic Method Call on Generic Functions

Tags: c#

I have the following two functions:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Save<TObject>(TObject object) where TObject : class
    {   
    }

    public void Save<TObject>(TObject object, String strValue) where TObject : class
    {
    }
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically call the first save function similar to the following:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(String strMethod) where T : class
{
    T myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    MyClass.GetType().GetMethod(strMethod, new Type[] { typeof(T) }).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(null, new[] { myObject });
 }
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, it is unable to match the first save function.  If I remove the `new Type[] { typeof(T) }` I am stuck with an ambiguity issue.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic type arguments won't match; the *specific* `T` in your `DoSomething` is **not** the same as the **open parameter** `TObject`. Instead, search for all `Save` methods, and then filter after that:

```
...GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == strMethod && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)...
```

Comment: Marc, that worked great!  The only change I had to make was .Invoke(MyClass, ... instead of .Invoke(null as arem mentioned below.  I was getting a non-static method error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will fix your issue, but you have to call Invoke() on an instance of MyClass, not sure why you are calling it with null.

Comment: Thanks armen, I gave Kudos to you in the answer above as well!